# Partial recovery from Radon transform

Tags: integral-transforms, integral-geometry, inverse-problems

Let $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ be an integrable function. Let $\eta$ be a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. We denote $p+\eta$ the affine subspace (a line) which is obtained by translation of $\eta$. The Radon transform for lines is then defined by
\begin{align*}
     (Rf)(\eta, p) = \int_{p + \eta} f \, \text{d}S.
\end{align*}
Denote the function $R_\eta f$ defined by $(R_\eta f)(p) = (Rf)(\eta,p)$ the radiograph along the direction $\eta$. It is a well-known result that if we know $(R_\eta f)$ for infinitely many distinct one-dimensional subspaces, then we can uniquely reconstruct $f$.

Now define the Radon transform along planes
\begin{align*}
     (P f)(\eta, q) = \int_{q + \xi} f \, \text{d}S,
\end{align*} 
where $\xi$ is now a two-dimensional subspace (and thus $q+\xi$ are planes). Suppose one has an infinite number of distinct $\xi$ which intersect in the one-dimensional subspace $L$, see the figure below.
[image]
Clearly one cannot reconstruct $f$, but intuitively I would expect that one can then get partial information about $f$, such as the values
\begin{align*}
   \int_{p+L} f \, \text{d}S = (Rf)(L,p)
\end{align*}
from the functions $P_\xi f$. However I haven't found a way to make this rigorous.

Comment: It is not true that if you know the line transform for infinitely many lines in three-space then you can recover the function. The best you can do is to know the value of the transform over certain three-dimensional manifolds in the space of lines.

Comment: It is well-known for the X-ray transform in n-dimensional space, that if one knows the radiographs (!) for infinitely many directions, then one can uniquely reconstruct the function under scrutiny.

Comment: what's your reference for this?

Comment: Sigurd Helgason: Integral Geometry and Radon Transforms, Proposition 7.8 and Andrew Markoe: Analytic Tomography, Theorem 3.144.

Comment: Take all lines on a plane inside three space, they are infinite in number and they comprise an infinite number of directions. However, knowing the value of the transform for only these lines does not allow you to reconstruct the function.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva: It seems that you are confused with the notion of radiographs. I did not say that knowing $\int_L f dS$ for an infinite number of distinct lines L is sufficient. Rather, I said that knowing $\int_{p+L} f dS$ for all displacements p and an infinite number of distinct lines L. For brevity one calls $R_L f$ defined by $(R_L f)(p) = (Rf)(L,p) = \int_{p+L} f dS$ a radiograph. Clearly for your specific example, one can reconstruct the function on all slices and by putting the slices together one gets the whole function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
\begin{align*}
 \widetilde{f}(p) := \int_{p+L} f \, \text{d}S = (Rf)(L,p).
\end{align*}
By doing so we are basically back in the left picture. We know the integral of $\widetilde{f}$ along all the lines $\eta_i$, simply because
\begin{align*}
      R_\eta \widetilde{f} = R_\xi f,
\end{align*}
which we know by assumption.

Thus by the uniqueness theorem for the X-Ray transform we may reconstruct $\widetilde{f}$, which is what I asked for.